# Python: How do you run a function without parameters?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Write a function `music_func` that takes 3 parameters *music type, music group, vocalist* and prints them all out as shown in the example below.

In case no input is provided by the user, the function should assume these values for the parameters: "Classic Rock", "The Beatles", "Freddie Mercury".

For example:

Input:

```
Alternative Rock,Pearl Jam,Chris Cornell
```

Output:

```
The best kind of music is Alternative Rock
The best music group is Pearl Jam
The best lead vocalist is Chris Cornell
```

> **Note :** The print statements will go inside the music_func(). For example: `print("The best kind of music is" + ...)`

```
#definition for music_func goes here
def music_func(a,b,c):
    if a is None or b is None or c is None:
        print("The best kind of music is Classic Rock")
        print("The best music group is The Beatles")
        print("The best lead vocalist is Freddie Mercury")
    else:
        print("The best kind of music is",a)
        print("The best music group is",b)
        print("The best lead vocalist is",c)
    return
def main():
    music, group, singer = input().split(',')
    music_func(music, group, singer)
    music_func() #This is suppose to print the first if-statements 
main()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. This question will likely attract many downvotes because it shows that you haven't learnt the basics of the language yet. Also the question sounds like a 1:1 copy of some homework assignment. Please consider reading a tutorial on default function parameters in Python.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I was attracted...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can utilize default arguments

```
def music_func(a="Beatles", b="Classic Rock", c="Freddie"):
```

Now calling the function with no arguments will default to using these options

Comment: Thank you! Did not even think of this.

Comment: So did you pass this homework assignment @BurmesePapi?